# Unity android build fail - Invalid command dx

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

i'm using unity 5.6.1f1 (the project was made really long time ago). I`m trying to build android apk, but having an error, saying
`Error:Invalid command dx`

```
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_201\bin\java.exe -Xmx2048M -Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir="C:/Users/gib-desk/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk\tools" -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -jar "D:\Unity\5.6.1f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer/Tools\sdktools.jar" -

stderr[
Error:Invalid command dx
]
stdout[

]
exit code: 64
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.RunCommandInternal (System.String javaExe, System.String sdkToolsDir, System.String[] sdkToolCommand, Int32 memoryMB, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.RunCommandSafe (System.String javaExe, System.String sdkToolsDir, System.String[] sdkToolCommand, Int32 memoryMB, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()
```

i downloaded and install android studio 2021.3.1.17 and got android sdk 33. I download tools_r25.2.5-windows and copy and paste it in `AppData\Local\Android_Sdk`.
Minimum API Level in player setting is set as Android 4.4 (kitkat) and Target API Level is automatic.

After searching in google, I checked my Assets/Plugins/Android folder  in unity, since it may be due to duplicated same files. However, in my Plugins/Android, there is no same named file. I have no idea how i can fix this issue...

Answer (score 0):

try this: Unity > Preferences > External Tools. uncheck everthing, close the window, then check again the paths, try compile.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I tried it but nothing changed. I created a new project and tried build test and it worked. Seems something in my project is wrong...